# Asp.net identity searching for email in username column in database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, authentication, asp.net-identity

I am trying to use email for login authentication in asp.net identity, So I've created a username field in register form, but when I try to login I get an error invalid login attempt. So In asp.net user table I copied the entered email and put it in the username column in this way I was successfully logged in [here is my user table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21LBu.png)

So its looking for email in username column, How to fix this issue?
this is my login method

```
        public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
        }
    }
```

this is my register method

```
   public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Name, Email = model.Email,};
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edited**
If user can enter either Username or Email, so we will make @ character for validation criteria. Here is the flow to be implemented:

1. If in the string @ is present, apply Email validation else apply Username format validation.
2. In case of valid Email, first we need to get Username. As it is considered that Username is unique so we can get it with userManager.FindByEmailAsync method.
3. Use Username for SignIn verification.

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
{
    ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
    if (model.Email.IndexOf('@') > -1)
    {
        //Validate email format
        string emailRegex = @"^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}" +
                               @"\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\" +
                                  @".)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$";
        Regex re = new Regex(emailRegex);
        if (!re.IsMatch(model.Email))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Email", "Email is not valid");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //validate Username format
        string emailRegex = @"^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$";
        Regex re = new Regex(emailRegex);
        if (!re.IsMatch(model.Username))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Username", "Username is not valid");
        }
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var userName = model.Email;
        if (userName.IndexOf('@') > -1)
        {
            var user =  await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
            if (user == null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
            }

        }
        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
    }
}
```

```
public class LoginViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Username")]
        public string Username{ get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
        public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: user has to enter both email and username but I want to use email for authentication.

Comment: @Haseeb in the example UserName or Email coming from a input-field. So you have Email/Username and password fields. Or you want to have 3 fields Email, Username and password?

Comment: 3 fields Email, Username and password

Answer (score 0):

The method is searching for username instead of email because you are making a mistake.

These are the overloads of `PasswordSignInAsync`.

**Overloads**

```
PasswordSignInAsync(String, String, Boolean, Boolean)
```

**Attempts to sign in the specified userName and password combination as an asynchronous operation.**

```
PasswordSignInAsync(TUser, String, Boolean, Boolean)
```

**Attempts to sign in the specified user and password combination as an asynchronous operation.**

So, in your case, you are simply using the first one.

**Edit**
To use the second overload, simply search for the user with such record.

```
var user=await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(vm.Email);

var result=await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user,vm.Password,false,false);

if(result.Succeeded){
//Do some other things.
}
```

Comment: getting error cannot convert from models.ApplicationUser to string

Comment: @Haseeb Of course. Where are you getting such error?

Comment: when I pass user variable in PasswordSignInAsync

Comment: @Haseeb see my edited answer, the method takes 4 parameters.